# Scraping Press Releases from a company website using crawlspider?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am looking to scrape all the press releases published by a company using Scrapy's `CrawlSpider`.

For the company BP, for instance each press release link includes `/press-releases/`, eg: [Here](https://www.bp.com/en/global/corporate/news-and-insights/press-releases/bp-appoints-tushar-morzaria-as-non-executive-director.html)

Yet the below code does not generate any output.
How should I change the `Linkextractor` rules? Or is this a case of the company website restricting scraping of press release pages?

Many thanks!

1. Spider code

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

class CompanyRulesSpider2(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'companymorerules2'
    allowed_domains = ['bp.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.bp.com/en/global/corporate/news-and-insights/press-releases.html']
    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='^(/investors/)'), callback='parse_items', follow=True
            ),
    ]

    def parse_items(self, response):
        print(response.url)
        title = response.css('h1::text').extract_first()
        url = response.url
        text = response.xpath('//div[@id="mw-content-text"]//text()').extract()
        lastUpdated = response.css('li#footer-info-lastmod::text').extract_first()
        lastUpdated = lastUpdated.replace('This page was last edited on ', '')
        print('Title is: {} '.format(title))
        print('title is: {} '.format(title))
        print('text is: {}'.format(text))
        print('weblink is {}'.format(url))
```

2. Current spider output

```
2020-07-26 15:55:04 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.bp.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-07-26 15:55:04 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.bp.com/en/global/corporate/news-and-insights/press-releases.html> (r
eferer: None)
2020-07-26 15:55:04 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `def parse_items` to `def parse`:

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class CompanyRulesSpider2(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'companymorerules2'
    allowed_domains = ['bp.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.bp.com/en/global/corporate/news-and-insights/press-releases.html']
    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='^(/investors/)'), callback='parse_items', follow=True
            ),
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.url)
        title = response.css('h1::text').extract_first()
        url = response.url
        text = response.xpath('//div[@id="mw-content-text"]//text()').extract()
        lastUpdated = response.css('li#footer-info-lastmod::text').extract_first() or ''
        lastUpdated = lastUpdated.replace('This page was last edited on ', '')
        print('Title is: {} '.format(title))
        print('title is: {} '.format(title))
        print('text is: {}'.format(text))
        print('weblink is {}'.format(url))
```

You need to override the `parse` method as it is the default callback for the spider.

Comment: Hi Ryan, Thank you for your response. I am not quite clear on your advice : my current code is indeed looking to override the parse method with a new "parse_items" function. I believe that removing the reference to parse_items would undo this override? Thank you for your clarification, Arthur

Comment: Your spider needs to have a `parse` method. Without this, it won't work. Therefore rename `parse_items` to `parse`